Perform multiple text replacements when copying a file
This Bash snippet generates copies of file IRC1.gjf to IRC2.gjf, etc etc
for i in {001..40}; do 
    cp IRC1.gjf "IRC$i.gjf" &&
    sed -i "s/1$/$i/g" "IRC$i.gjf"
done

But I want to edit each file content replacing "point1-F" by "point2-F" etc etc
so we end up with File40.gjf which contains "point40-F".
Didn't try anything because I this is not my field of expertise.

Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question.

add the extra desired changes to your sed command

Can you clarify the question? For example sed '/1$/' won't ever match point1-F; also you're generating the strings 001, 002, ..., but in your explanations you're talking about point1-F, point2-F, ...

It's not clear if you understand what sed -i "s/1$/$i/g" is doing. Note that echo "something1" |  sed "s/1$/001/" will produce something001, while echo "something1else" |  sed "s/1$/001/" doesn't change anything and  produces something1else. (The s/1$/more/ only operates on a line if the last character is 1. Good luck.

Copying the file and then running sed -i on it is clumsy and wasteful; you end up writing basically the same data twice.
The regular expression 1$ can only match once per line, so the g flag is unnecessary.
for i in {001..040}; do
    sed "s/1$/$i/" IRC1.gjf >"IRC$i.gjf"
done

To make additional modifications, ... make them.
for i in {001..040}; do
    sed -e "s/1$/$i/" \
        -e "s/point1-F/point$i-F/g" IRC1.gjf >"IRC$i.gjf"
done

The brace expansion {001..40} produces what I expect {001..040} to produce; I decided that this is probably better spelled out.
Your results will have the leading zeros, unlike what you seem to expect but just like the code you have already does. Perhaps clarify what exactly the code should do if this isn't what you want.

Brilliant, many thanks.  One small caveat it makes an additional substitution in the created files, for example in IRC033.gjf     (plain ascii file; Gaussian input)                                              %mem=120GB
%nproc=40
%oldchk=irc-TS1-fwd.chk
%chk=point033-Freq-fwd.chk
#p UwB97XD/6-311++G(d,p)  guess=(read)  geom=(check,ngeom=1) Freq Nosymm
point033-Freq-fwd
1  033                    %%%% this last 033 should have been a 1 (one) so why has it been changed?

@JohnSimmie please edit your question and add the relevant lines of the input file as a block of code

Because your previous script literally says to replace any line-final 1. That's what 1$ matches. If you don't want that, take it out.

Tried various combos of   "s/1$/si/ "     deleting / 1$  but it still wants to change the last line of the files which should read an unchanged  "1 1"

Without details about which occurrences should be replaced under which circumstances, we would completely have to guess. Perhaps accept this answer (or post your own answer and accept that if you prefer) and ask a new question with full details, including representative input data, expected result, and an explanation of under which circumstances a final 1 should be replaced, and when not.

sed is not intended to edit binary files like GIFs.
You need a tool that can handle binaries or programs able to do editing like ImageMagick or similar tools.

These are .gjf files. I'm assuming they are text files, as the OP seems to be saying the code they already have works.
